# How to fix the error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/trace' when export next.js project

Tags: next.js, nrwl-nx

I am developing using `nx` with `next`, when I try to run `npx nx export froentend`, it popup the following errors as below, does anyone have any ideas? By the way, I already run `npx nx build froentend` beforehand.

Thank you!

```
Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/trace'
Require stack:
- ~/Code/lumos/lumos-dex-ui/node_modules/@nrwl/next/src/executors/export/export.impl.js
- ~/Code/lumos/lumos-dex-ui/node_modules/@nrwl/tao/src/shared/workspace.js
- ~/Code/lumos/lumos-dex-ui/node_modules/@nrwl/tao/src/commands/run.js
- ~/Code/lumos/lumos-dex-ui/node_modules/@nrwl/tao/index.js
- ~/Code/lumos/lumos-dex-ui/node_modules/@nrwl/cli/lib/run-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rongliu/Code/lumos/lumos-dex-ui/node_modules/@nrwl/next/src/executors/export/export.impl.js:14:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because my `next.js` version is too low, ie., `v11`. After upgrading to the lates one, the issue is gone.